# Want to not index certain directories in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, indexing, eclipse-cdt, jvm-crash

Having a devil of a time trying to get eclipse c++ ide (on windows 7) working properly.

Using it to manage a large codebase, not building.  Want to be able to click-navigate around the code like one does in visual studio.

The indexer keeps crashing with a java heap space error.  I've increased the heap space in the eclipse.ini file (shown below) which helped only very slightly.  It takes literally HOURS to just get halfway through indexing the behemoth known as boost and then crashes... hasn't even touched the real codebase yet.

I would like the indexer to skip boost and just get on with managing the rest of the code, but not sure how to do that.  Tried a resource filter but that just kicked boost out of the project, which I don't think I want to do.

So, is there a way to have the eclipse indexer simply ignore certain folders, and second, is there a way to speed this up?

My eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms512m
-Xmx7168m
```

Comment: How much real memory does your machine have? If you only have 8GB of RAM, replace -Xmx7168m  with -Xmx4096m and see what happens .. you may be paging.  Have you looked at the task manager to see what resources are being consumed?

Comment: I do have 8GB.  I will try and see.  When I last let it go, it looked like it was memory that was being consumed.

Comment: Nah... did not make any difference.  Gets to about 42% of the way through boost and dies.  I've removed boost via a resource filter, but it's not my preferred solution and I consider it a workaround at best.  Visual Studio is able to quickly pinpoint the proper methods even in a massive lib like boost (without the need to spend time generating an index) so, one would assume eclipse should too.